# Does every computable ordinal admit a data structure corresponding to it?

Tags: data-structures

Assuming unbounded memory, it seems many data structures can contain an arbitrary finite number of members. However, *how* they store data differs. In particular, it seems useful to represent the said "how" by an ordinal. For examples:

- The list data structure is represented by the fixpoint of $O = 1 + O$, which is $\omega$.
- The list of lists is represented by the fixpoint of $O = \omega + O$, which is $\omega^2$.
- The binary tree is represented by the fixpoint of $O = 1 + 2 \times O$, which is $\omega$.
- The rose tree is represented by the fixpoint of $O = 1 + \omega \times O$, which is $\omega^\omega$.

I don't know how to formalize this idea, but I deem you all got the point. But what about bigger ordinals? Like $\epsilon_0$, $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_\omega$, $\zeta_0$, $\Gamma_0$, Ackermann ordinal, small Veblen ordinal, or large Veblen ordinal?